# How do I apply different functions to each group of 5 numbers in a text file in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a text file that contains tabular data that looks like this:

```
6.55900695241557        21.1155467550452        76.9138444071633        0.258463086828266       -0.509978952117326
6.16317799625041        21.2904678289099        81.9489765778723        0.64982496155813        1.22239329767002
6.22868289674435        21.1103020554023        84.2444654417416        -0.470608223724072      7.75676132386755
6.00468137751715        21.0293421931085        89.3910222757195        -1.02915556930388       9.01742486070105
```

I need to open this file and apply different functions to each set of 5 numbers. Some state will be changed between each function invocation. In Python, here is how I would do it:

```
def file2lists(file):
  for line in file.readlines():
    yield line.split()

foo = SomeObject()
for [a, b, c, d, e] in file2lists(someFile):
  foo.doSomethingThatChangesState(a, b, c, d, e)

bar = AnotherObject()
for [a, b, c, d, e] in file2lists(someFile):
  bar.doSomethingThatAlsoChangesState(a, b, c, d, e)
```

Is there an idiomatic way to do this in C++?

**UPDATE**

What I forgot to mention is that I would like to clearly encapsulate the reading of the data from the file. There are comments in that file that are prefixed with `#` which I need to filter out, and my current code is a very unreadable mixture between file streams, string streams and calls to the functions.

Is there a clean-ish way to write a function that sort-of behaves like a stream?

Comment: what version of C++? 
I here functional programming is better in the new ones.

Comment: For my purposes (this is test code anyway) any version of C++ is fine.

Comment: What problem are you having exactly? What's blocking you? Calling functions that change state is pretty much the bread-and-butter of C++.

Comment: I'm not sure how to write a function that generates the numbers from the text file, passing each group of 5 numbers to another function that happens to be a method of an object.

Comment: just a stray thought, how about a struct containing the five numbers and an istream_iterator for that?

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following might work for you (untested):

```
double a, b, c, d, e;
std::ifstream fp("file.dat");
while (fp >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e)
{
    function1(a, b, c, d, e);
    function2(a, b, c, d, e);
    myObject.function(a, b, c, d, e);
}
```

For `std::ifstream` you will need the `<fstream>` standard library.  This uses the `bool` operator of `fstream` [see here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_bool/).  You can then call any functions or object members you wish to change the state of/with or change some state directly inside the loop.

As an example of an object whose state is changed when `function` is called (also untested):

```
class Object
{
    double sum;
public:
    Object(void) : sum(0.0) {}
    void function(double a, double b, double c, double d, double e)
        { sum += a + b + c + d + e; }
    void print(void) { std::cout << sum << std::endl; }
};
```

Then in `main` you might do something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(void)
{
    Object myObject;
    double a, b, c, d, e;
    std::ifstream fp("data.dat");
    while (fp >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e)
    {
        myObject.function(a, b, c, d, e);
    }
    myObject.print();
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

For reading a data file with comment lines beginning with a `#` and never interleaved between the 5 value combinations you could do something like:

```
while (fp)
{
    while (isspace(fp.peek()) != 0) { fp.ignore(1); }
    if (fp.peek() == '#')
    {
        fp.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    else if (fp >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e)
    {
        myObject.function(a, b, c, d, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can replace that `&&` stuff with `fp >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I forgot to mention a few things (which are now in my updated question) but I'm upvoting your answer anyway.

Comment: @lindelof If you have only `#` for entire lines, my **EDIT** might be useful.  But if you have interleaved comments, I suspect you will have to keep your mixture of streams.